# Discover whether views/partials are being used within an MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This question has probably been asked before but my search failed to turn anything up. Is there an easy way to find out whether a view/partial is not being used in an MVC project? Currently I'm searching for the individual view name across the entire solution but wondering whether there's a tool out there that would make this job easier? I'm ideally looking for something that would provide a visual indication within Visual Studio if a view/partial is not being used.

I'm basically cleaning up an existing codebase and want to rip out any views that are not being used any more.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that, sorry.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case but thought I'd throw it out there

Comment: Search for Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial.  Also search for PartialViewResult.  I would think that would cover everything.

Comment: @jeff.eynon you would also need to add `Partial` as in `return Partial("blah")`

Comment: There is no better way??

Answer (score 6):

When I want to see if a view is used, I move it out of my project and enable view compilation. If a view is referenced from somewhere else it usually breaks.

enable view compilation by manually editing your mvc csproj file and setting the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```